# Spyder console lock-up caused by "IndexError: too many indices for array"

Tags: python, numpy, spyder

I have written a function that does some group averaging on a data set.  When I call this function it runs, returns the data which is then plotted.  During this call I get one warning:

```
warnings.warn("Warning: converting a masked element to nan.")
```

which appears not to affect the function call.  However, after the function returns, something is happening that locks up the console in which python is running (python 2.7, spyder 2.3.5.2, windows 7).  There is no error trace at the time of lock-up, but when I recover from this lock up I get the error trace given below.  This "index error" seems to be occurring in the python core and I don't see how to trace it back to my code.  Can anyone suggest how to determine the source of this error.

A bit more information on the process under which this error occurs:

When I first start Spyder I run my main calling module in the python console. The module completes correctly and the console returns to the command prompt. If I then click on the variable explorer the IDE locks up and further clicks cause the IDE to grey-out (other actions may have the same effect). I then try to close the IDE which prompts with the options to recover - which I do. The IDE recovers and that is when I get the "Index error" trace in the python console. I can then kill the console from the IDE (yellow triangle) and restart the console. If I then run the calling module again, it runs correctly (i.e. all outputs) but does not return to the command prompt in the restarted python console. Any clicks on the IDE then cause it to grey-out and I need to close the IDE to continue.

```
>>> Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\monitor.py", line 569, in run
    self.update_remote_view()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\monitor.py", line 450, in update_remote_view
    remote_view = make_remote_view(ns, settings, more_excluded_names)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\monitor.py", line 79, in make_remote_view
    minmax=settings['minmax'])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\dicteditorutils.py", line 202, in value_to_display
    value = repr(value)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\ma\core.py", line 3667, in __repr__
    data=str(self), mask=str(self._mask),
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\ma\core.py", line 3647, in __str__
    res.view(ndarray)[m] = f
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

The code that is called when this error occurs is:

```
def GroupSpectra(spectral, frequency, u, zmd, grp, covar=[1], prenorm=False):

    # expand non spectral inputs so they are samwe shape as spectral
    frequency = expand(frequency,spectral)
    u = expand(u,spectral)
    zmd = expand(zmd,spectral)
    grp = expand(grp,spectral)
    covar = expand(covar,spectral)
    scnt = expand(np.array([1]),spectral)

    # calc normalized freq
    nfreq = frequency*zmd/u

    # create frequency bins (freq by grps)
    grps = np.unique(grp)
    igrps = grps.size
    binfreq = np.power(10,np.arange(-5,2,0.1))
    iflen = binfreq.size
    binfreq = np.tile(binfreq,(igrps,1))
    binSpecSum = np.zeros(binfreq.shape)
    binSpecSS = np.zeros(binfreq.shape)
    binCount = np.ones(binfreq.shape) 
    binCoVar = np.zeros(binfreq.shape) 
    SpecAvg = np.zeros(binfreq.shape)
    CovAvg = np.zeros(binfreq.shape)
    SpecStd = np.zeros(binfreq.shape)

    # pre normalize powers ??
    if prenorm == True:
        spectral = spectral/covar

    # put powers in bins
    ig = 0
    for ig in np.arange(igrps):
        idg = grp == grps[ig]
        for ix in np.arange(0,iflen-1):
            flow = binfreq[0,ix]
            fhigh =  binfreq[0,ix+1] 
            idf = ((nfreq >= flow) & (nfreq < fhigh))
            idfg= idg & idf       
            binCount[ig,ix] = np.nansum(scnt[idfg])
            binSpecSum[ig,ix] =  np.nansum(spectral[idfg])
            binSpecSS[ig,ix] =  np.nansum(np.power(spectral[idfg],2.0))
            binCoVar[ig,ix] = np.nansum(covar[idfg])

    # avg spectra
    idb = binCount > 0.5
    SpecAvg[idb] = np.divide(binSpecSum[idb],binCount[idb]) 
    FreqAvg = binfreq
    SpecStd[idb] = np.sqrt(np.divide(binSpecSS[idb],binCount[idb])  - np.square(SpecAvg[idb]) )
    CovAvg[idb] = np.divide(binCoVar[idb],binCount[idb] )

    # pre normalize powers ??
    if prenorm == False:
        ida = CovAvg != 0.0
        idb = np.isfinite(CovAvg)
        idx = ida & idb
        SpecAvg[idx] = np.divide(SpecAvg[idx],CovAvg[idx])
       # SpecStd = SpecStd/CovAvg


    print(FreqAvg.shape)
    print(SpecAvg.shape)
    print(SpecStd.shape)
    return (FreqAvg,SpecAvg, SpecStd)
```

Comment: The exception seems to be occurring [within a function relating to Spyder's external Python shell](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/blob/master/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/monitor.py#L47-L69). Does this error occur when you run the same code outside of Spyder, e.g. in IPython or a plain Python shell?

Comment: Hi,  If I run the code from Spyder's IPython Qt console the same problem occurs.  However, if I run the module from a python interpreter started from the windows command prompt then the problem appears not to exist.

Comment: Also, if I run the module from an IPython shell started from Spyder the problem did not appear.

Comment: And a bit more into....    seems the first time I run the module in spyder's python console it doesn't cause a problem if I don't try and view the variables.  however if I try and run the module again without restarting spyder the module runs but locks up on completion.

Comment: Can you narrow it down to which specific variable(s) can't be viewed? It would be very helpful if you could cut down your code to a minimal test case where the error occurs and provide whatever inputs are necessary so that others can reproduce it.

Comment: Could you edit your question to include these details and delete them from the comments? Also, as I said before, it's hard to offer debugging help unless you can provide a [self-contained, reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I moved some of the details from the comments into the question.  I will try and produce a self-contained, reproducible example but at the moment, given the associated error messages and the fact that the code actually completes correctly, I'm not quite sure where to start.

Answer (score 0):

it took a while to track this down, but changing the following code resulted in the Spyder IDE not locking up on completion of the calling functions. The code was part of a function being used to resize some arrays.

The original two lines of code:

```
newsmall = np.tile(small, (colb,1))
newsmall = np.transpose(newsmall)
```

this code as changed to:

```
newsmall = np.resize(small,(rowb,1))
newsmall = np.tile(newsmall, (1,colb))
```

The array small had the dimensions (rowb,) before these two lines